# How to count number of functions in a C++ projects?

Tags: c++, refactoring, code-analysis, static-analysis

Is there any tool that analyse and reports number of functions (including member functions) in a C++ project?

I need to replace a global variable with a class member in a VC++ project. Then I need to introduce a local reference that points to new class member in functions that uses the global variable, so that the project compiles successfully. For that I need to calculate number of functions in that project. Then I can roughly calculate the time taken to do the change.

Comment: I would propose another solution - there are some IDE-s that provide the functionality to find usages of a variable(like the global variable you mention). I suggest using qtCreator(http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) and count the usages of the global variable. This will be more useful for you I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a static code analysis tool like [LOC Metrics](http://www.locmetrics.com/). It will count lines of code per function and output it to a .csv file. The number of lines in this output file is equal to the number of functions in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a VC++ project: generate a `.MAP` file. That lists every function; just count them.